# QTableView becomes very slow when multiple rows are selected

Tags: performance, qtableview

I have a model of about 1000 rows, with one of the columns changes every second.
I placed a cusom sort/filter model between the real model and the table view so as for the rows to be filtered immediately after they changed.

Now comes the problem:
If nothing is selected in the table view, everything just works fine; but when I have selected some rows, the table becomes lagging. The more rows selected, the more lagging it is.

Why? hope some one could give me a hint, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

While painting the (top) header for a table with selection enabled, the function:

```
bool QItemSelectionModel::isColumnSelected(int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
```

is called (twice for each column - but may vary on selection mode).
This function iterates through all selected rows (Line 1333 in "qitemselectionmodel.cpp" Qt 4.8.5).
So if there are many rows selected, the paint for each header column will get really slow.

Same for left header with cols/ rows switched.

The called functions are mostly not virtual - so there seems to be no way to avoid this without completely drawing your own header or hiding the header.

Maybe Qt should optimize this.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but there is a whole lot of potential places where performance can go down in QTableView.

The easiest way to pinpoint the slowdown is to profile the application. If you have the call(s)
that eats the cpu, it's far more simpler to deduce what is the cause and fix it.

Also you don't say much about the design of the custom sort/filter proxy. If you use QSortFilterProxyModel beware it does not scale well.